# GRE Tunneling not working

Tags: debian, ubuntu-16.04, tunneling, gre

i've been looking everywhere for a solution to this but have found really nothing. I was wondering if it is possible to forward ports such as 80 through an OpenVPN connection? I am using an OVH VPS with the preinstalled OpenVPN Debian 8 distro. Client port to server or something like that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This is bad diagram, but its better than nothing!
[click to see diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cftz.png) **on diagram webserver is on server1** my bad

Changed this to GRE tunneling.
I set the tunnel up on both ends like this, but i cannot use it.
Commands done on server 1:

```
ip tunnel add gre1 mode gre remote 66.xxx.xx.xx local 158.xx.xxx.xxx ttl 255
ip link set gre1 up
ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev gre1
```

Commands done on server 2:

```
ip tunnel add gre1 mode gre remote 158.xx.xxx.xxx local 66.xxx.xx.xx ttl 255
ip link set gre1 up
ip addr add 10.0.0.2/24 dev gre1
```

i cannot ping 10.0.0.2 from server 1, but i can obviously from server 2.

server 1 ip addr output:

```
root@server1:~# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group defaul                                                       t qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP gr                                                       oup default qlen 1000
link/ether fa:16:3e:17:34:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 158.xx.xxx.xxx/32 brd 158.69.202.194 scope global ens3
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe17:3430/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: gre0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1476 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
link/gre 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: gretap0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1462 qdisc noop state DOWN group defa                                                       ult qlen 1000
link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: gre1@NONE: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1476 qdisc noqueue state UNKNO                                                       WN group default qlen 1
link/gre 158.xx.xxx.xxx peer 66.xxx.xx.xx
inet 10.0.0.1/24 scope global gre1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::200:5efe:9e45:cac2/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route server 1:

```
root@server1:~# ip route
default via 158.xx.xxx.1 dev ens3
10.0.0.0/24 dev gre1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1
158.xx.xxx.1 dev ens3  scope link
```

ip addr server 2:

```
root@server2:~# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether d8:9d:67:d3:71:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.30/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp0s25
   valid_lft 73469sec preferred_lft 73469sec
inet6 fe80::3062:291f:ccf6:26aa/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:24:d7:e8:73:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.36/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlo1
   valid_lft 73461sec preferred_lft 73461sec
4: gre0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1476 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
link/gre 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
5: gretap0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1462 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: gre1@NONE: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1476 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
link/gre 66.xxx.xx.xx peer 158.xx.xxx.xxx
inet 10.0.0.2/24 scope global gre1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::200:5efe:42d3:132c/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route server 2:

```
root@server2:~# ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s25 proto static metric 100
10.0.0.0/24 dev gre1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2
169.254.0.0/16 dev gre1 scope link metric 1000
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s25 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.30 metric 100
```

Comment: I'm confused. Which port do you want to listen for connections and where do you want those connections to actually connect? Can you draw a diagram or somehow make this clear?

Comment: https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/vpn/tunnel-your-internet-traffic-through-an-openvpn-server

Comment: Without NAT you can just connect to the client...

Comment: You can use IPTables and policy routing features to accomplish this. Basically, you use IPTables to mark the packets with a specific routing tag, and then add separate routing rules for the routing tags. However, I don't know any closer details on the subject.

Comment: I am now attempting GRE tunneling. They both ping the physical IP addresses but they wont ping through the tunnel.

Comment: Now i can ping server 1 from server 2 but i cannot ping server 2 from server 1.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you want a VPN connection/tunnel between servers 1 and 2. And then a reverse proxy (nginx/apache/haproxy/varnish/...) on server1 that forwards all requests over the tunnel to server2.

Comment: yes but im making a GRE Tunnel now. I can ping both 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2 on server 2 but i cant on server 1